# Didn't find class "my.package.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList

Tags: dex

I am using android.support.multidex, and have faced with a problem(
I get this error "Didn't find class "my.package.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList". 
MyApplication extends MyAbstractApplication, which is .aar in Maven repository and extends MultiDexApplication . And i override attachBaseContext(Context base) in MyApplication.
What am i doing wrong? 
multidex.keep:

```
android/support/multidex/BuildConfig.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V19.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V4.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor$1.class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor.class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil$CentralDirectory.class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil.class
```

PS: If i use Maven *.aar like a submodule everything works fine.
Thanks for help!

Comment: I am having the same issue as well....  But in my case, i am declaring the MultiDexApplication in the AndroidManifest.xml, if that helps someone clarify..

Comment: @AndrewPhillips If you will decide to add something extra into your Application, you will have an ClassCastException.

Comment: @AndrewPhillips Alex's solution works fine, but in additional you must to add into your --main-dex-list file all classes which uses in Application OnCreate method

Comment: you are correct, i realized the issue i was having as well.   Mine was specifically that i had the multidex library in my path but was not including it in the APK.   works fine now, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you subclassing the Application class, your derived classes should be present in main dex file.
Add them to your --main-dex-list file. As per your example:

> my/package/MyApplication.class
>    my/package/MyAbstractApplication.class

Btw, to add MultiDex support you have to either extend MultiDexApplication **or** override attachBaseContext to call MultiDex.install. Doing both makes no sense.

Additionally, you can [generate the main-dex-list file](http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/generating-main-dex-list-file.html).

Comment: Note that to call "MultiDex.install" after super call of "attachBaseContext" Method